# angular.js cant take result from view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button in view

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-white" ng-click="getUser('{{customer.id}}')"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Görüntüle </a>
```

this button is in ng-repeat, customer.id is string when I call it from controller.js

```
$scope.getUser = function (param) {
            console.log(param);

        };
```

console.writes

> {{customer.id}}

as result. This language makes me crazy, Where do I make mistake

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to pass angular expression in your `ng-click`. So change your `ng-click` to

```
ng-click="getUser(customer.id)"
```